# How to insert spaces correctly between words when the sentence has spaces removed using R?

Tags: r

I have some survey data where item names were the survey text with spaces removed.
I want to add the spaces back in. Obviously this requires some knowledge of the English language.

- Is there an R function that can correctly insert spaces into a sentence after spaces have been removed?
- Alternatively, are there text processing functions that would assist in this process (e.g., by determining whether a sequence of letters is a word or non-word)?

Here is some sample data, but any function should work on any arbitrary reasonable sentence:

```
x <- c("Shewrotehimalongletter,buthedidn'treadit.", 
      "Theshootersaysgoodbyetohislove.", 
      "WritingalistofrandomsentencesisharderthanIinitiallythoughtitwouldbe.", 
      "Letmehelpyouwithyourbaggage.", 
      "Pleasewaitoutsideofthehouse.", 
      "Iwantmoredetailedinformation.", 
      "Theskyisclear;thestarsaretwinkling.", 
      "Sometimes,allyouneedtodoiscompletelymakeanassofyourselfandlaughitofftorealisethatlifeisn’tsobadafterall.")
```

source: http://www.randomwordgenerator.com/sentence.php

Comment: Your problem reminds me of [a recent article in the New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/03/21/han-dynasty-tables-for-two), which mentioned that the website for the restaurant Han Dynasty has run into problems with porn filters, as its URL, www.handynasty.net, can be read in two different ways.

Comment: Have you tried any NLP word tokenizers yet? They likely won't work straight, but could tell you if guesses are words if you want to write your own function.

Comment: @eipi - The classic Pen Island problem.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at expertsexchange.

Comment: @alistaire I'm not familiar with NLP word tokenizers. Are there any R packages that might assist with this or is it necessary to go out into the broader programming eco-system?

Comment: The `openNLP` package should do it, though you'll need to read the docs for how to install the language modules and actually use the thing. It's designed to fit in with the `NLP` package.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an answer, but it's more of a 'there probably isn't a unique answer' answer.

The `ScrabbleScore` package has the 2006 tournament word list, so I'll use that as my approximation of 'English words' to search.

```
library(ScrabbleScore)    
data("twl06")
```

We can check if a word is 'English' by looking for it in that list.

```
findword <- function(string) {
  if (string %in% twl06) return(string) else return(1)
}
```

Let's use a nice ambiguous piece of text, shall we? This one caused a bit of a stir because it was used as a hashtag for Susan Boyle's album party

```
x <- c("susanalbumparty")
```

We can check substrings for 'English' words and progressively shorten the string as we find words. This could be done from the start or the end, so I'll do both to demonstrate that the answer is hardly unique

```
sentence_splitter <- function(x) {

  z <- y <- x
  words1 <- list()
  while(nchar(z) > 1) {
    while(findword(y) == 1 & nchar(y) > 1) {
      y <- substr(y, 2, nchar(y))
    }
    if (findword(y) != 1) words1 <- append(words1, y)
    y <- z <- substr(z, 1, nchar(z) - nchar(y))
  }

  z <- y <- x
  words2 <- list()
  while(nchar(z) > 1) {
    while(findword(y) == 1 & nchar(y) > 1) {
      y <- substr(y, 1, nchar(y) - 1)
    }
    if (findword(y) != 1) words2 <- append(words2, y)
    y <- z <- substr(z, 1 + nchar(y), nchar(z))
  }

  return(list(paste(unlist(rev(words1)), collapse = " "),
              paste(unlist(words2), collapse = " ")))

}
```

The results:

```
sentence_splitter("susanalbumparty")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "us an album party"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "us anal bump arty"
```

Note: this finds the longest substring searching in each direction (as I'm shortening the string). You could also do this by expanding the string to find the shortest. To do this properly, you need to look at all 'English' substrings that leave only valid words remaining.

Lastly, you will notice that 'susan' doesn't get matched, as it's not a 'valid English word' under this definition.

Hopefully that's enough to convince you that this isn't going to be simple.

Update: trying this on some of your examples (it actually doesn't do too badly once you `tolower` and remove punctuation)... That last one is a doozy, but the rest seem to do okay

```
unlist(lapply(sub("[[:punct:]]", "", tolower(x))[1:7], sentence_splitter))
#> "she wrote him along letter the did re adit"                                     
#> "shew rote him along letter but he did tread it"                                 
#> "the shooter says goodbye to his love"                                           
#> "the shooters ays goodbye to his love"                                           
#> "writing alist of random sentence sis harder ani initially though tit would be"  
#> "writing alist of randoms en ten es is harder than initially thought it would be"
#> "let me help you with your baggage"                                              
#> "let me help you withy our baggage"                                              
#> "please wait outside of the house"                                               
#> "please wait outside oft heh use"                                                
#> "want more detailed information"                                                 
#> "want more detailed information"                                                 
#> "the sky is clear the stars are twinkling"                                       
#> "the sky is clear the stars are twinkling"
```